# RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment

Tags: python, windows, conda

Having trouble installing a third party library and I have not seen this error before using Windows 10 with Anaconda installed:

```
C:\Users\XYZ>conda env create -f python3.6-environment-windows.yml
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages
certifi-2018.1.18    | 144 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
mkl-2018.0.1         | 155.2 MB  | ############################################################################ | 100%
pytz-2018.9          | 229 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
icc_rt-2019.0.0      | 9.4 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
icu-58.2             | 21.8 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
pip-9.0.1            | 1.7 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
xz-5.2.3             | 348 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
sip-4.18.1           | 269 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
libpng-1.6.36        | 1.3 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
vc-14                | 985 B     | ############################################################################ | 100%
numpy-1.14.0         | 3.7 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
python-3.6.4         | 17.6 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
jpeg-9c              | 314 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
wheel-0.30.0         | 85 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
wincertstore-0.2     | 13 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
freetype-2.9.1       | 475 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
scipy-1.0.0          | 13.0 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
pyparsing-2.3.1      | 54 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
kiwisolver-1.0.1     | 60 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
qt-5.6.2             | 55.6 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
python-dateutil-2.7. | 218 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
vs2015_runtime-14.0. | 1.9 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
ca-certificates-2017 | 489 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
tk-8.6.7             | 3.5 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
setuptools-38.4.0    | 540 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
matplotlib-2.2.2     | 6.5 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
six-1.12.0           | 21 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
openssl-1.0.2n       | 5.4 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
pyqt-5.6.0           | 4.5 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
zlib-1.2.11          | 236 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
tornado-5.1.1        | 665 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
sqlite-3.22.0        | 907 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
cycler-0.10.0        | 8 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

In reference to the instructions here - https://enigma.co/catalyst/install.html#installing-with-conda

Comment: Note that this problem was reported yesterday on the conda bugtracker, but [for `setuptools` instead of `requests`](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9337).

Comment: `conda update --force conda` worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: As @MuhammadUsman says above and @alekha says here:https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8149#issuecomment-477799562, `conda update --force conda` solves the problem.

Comment: Saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

running `conda update conda` before solved the problem for me

Comment: When I tried `conda update conda`, the same error occurs. Like `RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.`

Comment: this will force a newer minor version of python upon you, not always a good solution therefore

Comment: Worked for me but on a sudo

Comment: I ran    conda update conda    and then ran conda update --all, this was able to do the job

Comment: `conda update conda`, `sudo conda update conda`, and `conda update --all` all yield the very same error for me on Mac OS Mojave.

Answer (score 93):

I had the same problem on Mac Mojave, and in my case run `conda update --force conda` first worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to install textacy, thanks.

Comment: WARNING: The --force flag will be removed in a future conda release. --force is not recommended.

Comment: Still having the same issue with `conda update --force conda` on my MBP running Mojave.

Comment: I tried this, and now I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libarchive'` from `conda update conda` and similar.

Comment: @pjpj: correct. I used `conda update --force-reinstall conda -y` to perform the update instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
conda update --force conda
```

will solve : Verifying transaction: failed Remove Error: 'request' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda is operating environment.

Comment: `conda update --force conda`


WARNING: The --force flag will be removed in a future conda release.
         See 'conda update --help' for details about the --force-reinstall
         and --clobber flags.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me on Linux:

1. Uninstall the package via pip:

   ```
   pip uninstall setuptools
   ```
2. Reinstall using the following command:

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda setuptools
   ```

Consider also that system packages (`python3-setuptools`, `python-setuptools` in Ubuntu) might need to be removed.

Comment: `conda install -c anaconda setuptools` solves the issue on my MBP + Mojave. Thanks!

Comment: While `pip uninstall setuptools` worked, `conda install -c anaconda setuptools` just caused the same error. And now I don't have setuptools.

Comment: why setuptools? The question is on the `requests` package.

Comment: This worked for me on windows.

Answer (score 8):

```sh
conda update --force conda
```

this worked for me in win64 when I

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/sdvillal openslide-python
```

Answer (score 5):

Silly point to make here but I've been caught by this before: *you may not be in the environment you think you are*. Just before killing off any package run a quick check to see:

```
conda env list
```

Performing ops on the base environment can cause issues, so you may [want to create or change environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do the following steps to get it to work for me

```
conda update --force conda
```

This will run and update conda then run the following command

```
conda update conda
```

At each stage update all packages. After that, everything should work fine.

Comment: This worked for me. I was surprised I needed to run `conda update conda` after I had just forced the update in the previous command. But I did! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, which was due to a bad installation of a package (OpenEXR in my case).
Try to verify your package with `conda list yourPackage`.
If you find which one it is, prefer installing it with pre-built packages here : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

A stack-overflow thread that helped me : [Python 2.7, PIP: "Failed building wheel for ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320033/python-2-7-pip-failed-building-wheel-for)

EDIT : 
Two friends had the same error, one solved it by installing/executing with admin rights.
The other one succeeded by creating a new virtual environnement for python.

Comment: Thanks, building the wheel manually from the prebuilt packages worked from someone on Github.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, on macos, after removing all R packages installed by anaconda. Unfortunately, the only solution I found is to reinstall anaconda. Alternatively, you could download miniconda shell script installer, run it with `-U` option and point the installer at your conda directory. This fixed the issue for me while maintaining settings such as channel priority. However, many of previously installed packages were not importable (Python couldn't find them) and i ended up re-installing all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try to use the command prompt to install wheel file if you get an error something like this(as shown in picture) then you must install that wheel file:

[image]

Extra(how to install wheel file from command prompt):

> - download wheel file as per the system specifications:  -search required file here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  -e.g.
>     bsddb3    -click bsddb3 and search required file
> - open command prompt on your system
> - change the location on the command prompt to: where you have downloaded wheel file e.g C:\Users\Name\Downloads
> - go to the location, where you have installed python>>go to script>> copy the path  (e.g C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts)
> - write the command, to install wheel file using pip install  (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\pip install
>     copy_name_of_the_wheel_file)
> - run the command

Answer (score 0):

try conda env create --force -f python3.6-environment-windows.yml
I'm not sure exactly where to place it but I use the --force whenever I run into issues like this like conda update --force conda or conda install --force ...
use it as last solution since it force conda to perform the command and you might run into some issues later on

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the problem
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.

[image]

As the following way:

- pip uninstall setuptools
- conda update conda
- conda update setuptools

[image]

and then check tools

[image]

I haven't met any mistakes yet, but help me correct my way , if something wrong, please

Comment: Welcome to SO, please put exclamation marks before the links to display the images (like ![enter image description here]() )

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to alter the base env, for me, I simply switch to the env that I created and it worked without any other modification.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For me, deactivating the current conda environment solves the problem, i.e. run `conda deactivate` before upgrading.

Comment: This answer worked for me, for my command:  ```conda install -c conda-forge python-dotenv --name my_dashboard```  The command needs to be executed OUTSIDE the target environment to modify "infrastructure packages" (like requests) that conda needs to manage the environment itself.