# I get a 'requests' error when I try to update everything with the conda command

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, anaconda, conda

I tried to update my base conda environment this morning and received the following error after running the 'conda update --all' command.

> RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
> conda's operating environment.

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure how exactly to remedy this since the requests module already exists in that environment folder.

Comment: try  `conda update conda` first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392995/removeerror-requests-is-a-dependency-of-conda-and-cannot-be-removed-from-cond)